# apt-get update error "failed to fetch" and "temporary failure resolving"

Tags: debian, ssh, apt, upgrade

This is what I get when I run the apt-get update on my debian 11 server.

Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://packages.sury.org/php bullseye InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'packages.sury.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'security deb.debian.org'
Err:5 htttp://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.nodesource.com'
Err:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'repo.mysql.com'

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye/security InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch

Comment: cross-posted: https://serverfault.com/questions/1117552/apt-get-update-error-in-debian-11-temporary-failure-resolving-and-also-failed . There OP wrote that "it seems that I do not have internet access at all, the server was connected and working fine until Monday when an administrator was installing company specific software and lost ssh connection".